# Updating current user's email address in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm having a problem updating the current user's email address in Meteor. The problem code is here (it's all client code):

```
var id = Meteor.userId();
if (firstName) {
Meteor.users.update(
    { _id: id }, 
    { $set: { "profile.firstName": firstName }}
)};
if (lastName)  {
Meteor.users.update(
    { _id: id }, 
    { $set: { "profile.lastName":  lastName  }}
)};    
var oldEmail = Meteor.user().emails[0].address;
if (newEmail) {
Meteor.users.update(
    { _id: id, 'emails.0.address': oldEmail }, 
    { $set: { 'emails.0.address': newEmail }}
)};
```

The first two lines work fine (user can update their first and last names), but the last update fails with the following error showing in the console:
"errorClass {isClientSafe: true, error: 403, reason: "Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID."

I don't understand the error, because I **AM** updating by ID--or at least I think I am.

Also: if I remove the reference to the old email, I get a simple "Update failed. Access denied" error in the console instead of the above-mentioned error.

Is there a way to fix this with client-side code only?

(I realize I'll also need to reset the "verified" key back to false, but that's a different issue I guess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not edit the `emails` array directly. The Accounts package has utility functions for this use case, see [Accounts.addEmail](https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-addEmail) and [Accounts.removeEmail](https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-removeEmail).

First you will need to invoke a Method since these functions must be performed on the server.

Client js:

```
if (newEmail) {
  Meteor.call('updateEmail', newEmail, err => {
    if (err) console.log(`Error updating email address: {err}`);
  });
}
```

server:

```
Meteor.methods({
  updateEmail(newAddress) {
    const userId = this.userId;
    if (userId) {
      const currentEmail = Meteor.users.findOne(userId).emails[0].address;
      Accounts.addEmail(userId, newAddress);
      Accounts.removeEmail(userId, currentEmail)
    }
    return;
  }
});
```

You should also validate in your method that the new email address is a string that has an email address pattern.

Comment: This worked perfectly! I only had to add another closing brace before the closing parenthesis in the server code. Maybe you could edit your answer with that and I'll accept/upvote it.

Comment: Closing brace added